# OpenCV(python): how to use ccm.ColorCorrectionModel.setWeightsList(p)?

Tags: python, opencv, github, colors

I am struggling to use the method ccm.ColorCorrectionModel.setWeightsList(p) correctly.
I can not get the right format of the parameter p.
First the ccm.ColorCorrectionModel is filled with source and reference values of the format/shape (24,1,3) -all double.
So I tried a numpyarray for parameter p also of format (24,1,3) -all double for the weightsList.
But the runtime breaks (see below).
Any idea whats wrong or is there a small python app around that uses the method .setWeightsList() successfully, where I can see how the source and weight values have to be linked?

Code:

```
src = np.array([...]) # array of shape (24,1,3) values 0-255
ref = np.array([...]) # array of shape (24,1,3) values 0-255
model = cv2.ccm.ColorCorrectionModel(src/255, ref/255, cv2.ccm.COLOR_SPACE_sRGB);

w = np.array([...]) # array of shape (24,1,3) all values 1.0
model.setWeightsList(w)
model.run() => error
```

Error:
"cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:214: error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::binary_op' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a C++ example in OpenCV source code file [test_ccm.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.7.0/modules/mcc/test/test_ccm.cpp).

In the example, the size of the weights_list mat is `(24, 1)`.
Relevant part from `test_ccm.cpp` file:

```c++
Mat weights_list_ = (Mat_<double>(24, 1) <<
                        1.1, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 0,
                        1.3, 0, 0, 1.4, 0, 0,
                        0.5, 0, 0, 0.6, 0, 0,
                        0.7, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0);
```

---

Modify the size of `w` to be `(24, 1)`.

Example:

```
w = np.array(np.ones((24, 1))) # array of shape (24,1) all values 1.0
model.setWeightsList(w)
model.run() # Works
```

---

It looks like each weight refers an RGB triplet (each weight refers [red, green, blue]).

Note: I can't really tell what is the purpose of the Weights List (it seems to be undocumented), and following the source code is difficult.

Comment: Hi Rotem, thanks for the link, I tried as format for the weights list : (24) , (24,1), (24,3), (24,1,3)  all give the same error

Comment: I am using OpenCV version 4.7 and it's working using `w = np.array(np.ones((24, 1)))` (there are no errors). I have no way knowing why it's not working in your case. Can you please post an executable code sample - add import statements and replace `[...]` with values. Make sure your posted code sample is executable.

Comment: Hi Rotem, does your code also run into a crash when inserting before run() : 
    model.setCCM_TYPE(cv2.ccm.CCM_4x3)

Comment: Yes, when using both `model.setCCM_TYPE(cv2.ccm.CCM_4x3)` and `model.setWeightsList(w)` there is an error: "error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'cv::arithm_op'"

Answer (score 0):

concerning the format of the weightsList Rotems code is right,
but at my code the problem is not the format of the weightsList, it is the format of the ccm. And I do not understand how this is linke.
My code which creates somehow the format problem :
model.setCCM_TYPE(cv2.ccm.CCM_4x3)
when I change to this everything is running fine :
model.setCCM_TYPE(cv2.ccm.CCM_3x3)
Rotem, thanks for the link, that leads me inthe right direction to locate the problem.